# jQuery Deferred should work but doesn't

Tags: jquery, spotify, deferred

I have a spotify app and want to wait for a loop to finish. But it only works after reloading my app once.

```
function matchRecommendations(result) {
var deferreds = new Array();
for ( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    // Async wait
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    deferreds.push(dfd.promise());

    ...

    // Wait for search to finish
    search.tracks.snapshot(0, 1).done(
            function(snapshot) {
                // If match was found => create recommendation object
                var uri = snapshot._uris[0];
                var meta = snapshot._meta[0];
                if ($.type(meta) !== "undefined") {
                    if ($.type(meta.name) === "string") {
                        console.log(uri);
                        var rec = new Recommendation(uri, meta,
                                explanation, score);
                        RadioView.prototype.addRecommendation(rec);
                    }
                }

                // Async task finished
                dfd.resolve();
            });
}

return deferreds;
}
```

Here I'm calling the above method and want to wait for it to finish.

```
 $.when.apply($, matchRecommendations(result)).done(
                            function() {
                                console.log("finished");
                                RadioView.prototype.render();
                            });
```

I can't see the Problem why this souldn't work. The problem is the "done" callback is not executed when loading for the first time. If I reload the app it works just fine
...Anything wrong with the Deferred Stuff?

Comment: If `snapshot()` already returns a promise, something the use of `done()` would imply, why are'nt you just returning that promise instead of creating a new one ?

Comment: Sure you do not get js errors or ajax errors in the process? Cause your when applied to this array of deferreds seems to be fully ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed an old familiar scope issue, by which there is only one scope within `matchRecommendations()` and all vars set in its `for` loop each has its final value and no other when that loop exits.

There's a number of ways around this, the simplest (as you are already using jQuery) being to loop through the `result` array with `jQuery.each()`.

The code would look like this :

```
function matchRecommendations(result) {
    var promises = [];
    $.each(result, function(i, rslt) {
        ...
        var p = search.tracks.snapshot(0, 1).done(function(snapshot) {
            var uri = snapshot._uris[0];
            var meta = snapshot._meta[0];
            if ($.type(meta) !== "undefined" && $.type(meta.name) === "string") {
                console.log(uri);
                RadioView.prototype.addRecommendation(new Recommendation(uri, meta, explanation, score));
            }
        });
        promises.push(p);
    });
    return promises;
}
```

Notes:

- As @adeneo points out, `search.tracks.snapshot()` returns a promise (at least it seems safe to assume it does), so it's unnecessary to create a secondary Deferred to be resolved in cascade.
- (Doh!) Without a secondary Deferred, the scope issue actually disappears, so you can return to the `for` loop if you wish.

Comment: All your suggestions work fine ;)...but like my first approach not the first time. So I guess the deferred stuff isn't the problem after all. Have to look at that great docs of the spotify preview api...Anyway rewrote my method to use jquery each, thx!

Comment: Sven, I can't really comment on Spotify because I'm not a Spotify person, but it seems they have a strong commitment to documentation. Hopefully you will be OK. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have scoping issues, which is why probably only the last deferred will get resolved. I don't know how you check for the `done` callback (not) being executed, but the scoping issue might be causing your problems (unless `result.length` happens to be 1).

You need to create a new scope for each deferred:

```
var deferreds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  (function(dfd) {
    deferreds.push(dfd.promise());
    search.tracks.snapshot(0, 1).done(function(snapshot) {
      ...
      dfd.resolve();
    });
  })($.Deferred());
};
```

If `result` happens to be an array, you can create a bit more readable code:

```
var deferreds = $.map(result, function() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  search.tracks.snapshot(0, 1).done(...);
  return dfd.promise();
});
```